# Securing XHR Request to AngularJS templateURLs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security

*I apologize if I am misunderstanding something here =)

In angular, templates are requested via XHR from the server and loaded into the application, then kept in a cache. If I load a page and look at the networking, you can see the following request:

Remote Address:XX.XXX.X.XX:80
Request URL:http://{host}/views/notifications.html
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

I have locked down the path with context root of `/views` on the application server.

**The question**: Is there a way to provide credentials of username/password to the templateURL to use auth when it fetches the inital template? If so, does Angular provide a mechanism for this, or would it be something I would have to fork and customize. Or maybe there is a better approach to enable page level security in an AngularJS application.

`I want to avoid simply hiding and showing pages. The idea being you couldn't just open a console and switch some booleans and display a page`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you may want to use ui-router to change views/templates. Using ui-router, you can use states and check for authentication in the resolve statement like so:

```
$stateProvider.$state('notifications', {
   url: '/notifications',
   templateUrl: 'notifications.html',
   resolve : {
     auth: function(AuthenticationService) { // create an authentication service
       if (!AuthenticationService.Auth) { // check for authentication
         $state.go('login) // go to a different states
       }
      }
   }
})
```

The resolve is basically a promise to do some stuff before rendering the template.

Additionally:

Instead of using a get requests to fetch the templates, look into the $templateCache service.

$templateCache lets you cache the templates using the put method and a key/value. This way, whenever you need to use templateUrl you can just inject the $templateCache service and reference the template by key like so:

```
$templateCache.put('notifications.html', '<div> Your Template Here</div>');
```

Then in a directive for example :

```
 app.directive('someDirective', function($templateCache){

  return {
   restrict: 'ECMA',
   templateUrl: 'notifications.html'
  }
 })
```

Similarly if you're using ng-include in your html you can reference the template in the same way :

```
<div ng-include='notifications.html'></div
```

You will also want to look into gulp-angular-templateCache to help you concatenate all your html templates into string values to insert into your $templateCache.

Additionally, you will want to run all the template caching in the run block of your angular code.

The run block in your angular application could look something like this if you're using the $templateCache service:

```
angular.module("sampleShoppingApp", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("cart-footer.html","<div class=\'title cart-footer\'>Checkout</div>");
$templateCache.put("cart-item.html","<div ng-if=\'!emptyProducts\'>\n  <div class=\'card product-card\' ng-repeat=\'product in products track by $index\'>\n    <div class=\'item item-thumbnail-right product-item\'>\n      <img ng-src=\'{{product.images[0]}}\' class=\'product-image\' ion-product-image=\'product\'>\n      <h3 class=\'product-title\'>{{product.title}}</h3>\n      <p class=\'product-description\'>{{product.description}}</p>\n\n      <i class=\'icon ion-plus-round icon-plus-round\' mouse-down-up ng-click=\'addProduct(product)\'></i>\n         <span class=\'product-quantity\'>{{product.purchaseQuantity}}</span>\n      <i class=\'icon ion-minus-round icon-minus-round\' mouse-down-up ng-click=\'removeProduct(product)\'></i>\n\n      <span class=\'product-price\'>${{product.price}}</span>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n  <div>\n    <br><br><br><br>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n<div class=\'empty-cart-div\' ng-if=\'emptyProducts\'>\n  <h3 class=\'empty-cart-header\'>Your bag is empty!</h3>\n  <i class=\'icon ion-bag empty-cart-icon\'></i>\n</div>");
$templateCache.put("checkout-footer.html","<div class=\'title purchase-footer\'>Pay</div>");
$templateCache.put("checkout.html","\n<span class=\'checkout-form-description\'>Please enter your credit card details:</span>\n\n<div class=\'list checkout-form\'>\n  <checkout-name ng-if=\'hasNameDir\'></checkout-name>\n  <checkout-card></checkout-card>\n  <checkout-address ng-if=\'hasAddressDir\'></checkout-address>\n  <checkout-email ng-if=\'hasEmailDir\'></checkout-email>\n</div>\n\n<h2 class=\'checkout-total\'>Total: ${{total}}</h2>\n");
$templateCache.put("gallery-item.html","<div class=\'ion-gallery-content\'>\n  <div class=\'card gallery-card\' ng-repeat=\'product in products track by $index\'>\n    <div class=\'item gallery-item\'>\n      <div class=\'gallery-image-div\'>\n        <img ng-src=\'{{product.images[0]}}\' class=\'gallery-product-image\'>\n      </div>\n      <h3 class=\'gallery-product-title\'>{{product.title}}</h3>\n      <h3 class=\'gallery-product-price\'>${{product.price}}</h3>\n      <div class=\'gallery-product-add\' ng-click=\'addToCart(product)\'>\n        <h3 class=\'gallery-product-add-title\' cart-add>{{addText}}</h3>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>");
$templateCache.put("partials/address-line-one.html","<label class=\'item item-input address-line-one\'>\n  <input type=\'text\' ng-model=\'checkout.addressLineOne\' placeholder=\'Address Line 1\'>\n</label>");
$templateCache.put("partials/address-line-two.html","<label class=\'item item-input address-line-two\'>\n  <input type=\'text\' ng-model=\'checkout.addressLineTwo\' placeholder=\'Address Line 2\'>\n</label>");
$templateCache.put("partials/address.html","<div class=\'item item-divider\'>Address: </div>\n<address-one-input></address-one-input>\n<address-two-input></address-two-input>\n<city-input></city-input>\n<state-input></state-input>\n<zip-input></zip-input>\n");
}]);
```

Comment: so how would this be secure? What would be stopping someone from opening up a console in chrome, and logging out templates within a controller that has the $templateCache injected? Thanks for your suggestion! `even if the server returned the available htmlKeys a user would have available, the keys themselves would still need to be used initializing the templates with the put method, correct?`

Comment: I like the idea of calling templateCache to load the partials. I think I am still going implement a secure GET request that will fetch my HTML source, and then that returned source can be cached into `$templateCache` via the put method. Then will pull it where needed. Good answer!

Comment: @DaveGavigan  Thanks for the vote up, however, I'm a little confused by your first comment. Your should not actually contain any sensitive information unless they are actually loaded into the document. If you're templates aren't loaded into the DOM, then the expression placeholders will not be evaluated and a user cannot have access to them!

Comment: well i see what your saying. however if i have something like `if(Authenticated){$templateCache.put('key', 'source')}` ... this may not get evaluated, but the source is still right there in the client. You could technically still get to it if you were savvy enough. So, id rather make a request to the server, fetch the html, then cache it on return

Comment: @DaveGavigan You should be using angular expressions/scope-variables in your html instead of the actual data. i.e. {{API_Key}} instead of the actual api key {{wrtbhtr493qewjefogirasdfgdihbr!9er98whewgrei}} (random key example); Your controllers/models should be the stuff to handle the actual data.